# Why Won’t My Pokémon Evolve

Tags: pokemon-go

Since I updated 2 days ago none of my Pokémon will evolve Scyther, Anorith, Caterpie just to name a few. I deleted the app and reinstalled it that didn’t help! And yes, they are all ready to evolve! When I hit the evolve button it takes me back to the Pokémon screen!

Answer (score 17):

This is a UI bug that I have experienced myself. Essentially, the exit button slightly overlaps the evolve button. As a result, trying to evolve a Pokémon will exit the screen rather than evolving.

The following are solutions to get past this bug:

- Press the far left side of the evolve button (credits to @Amy B)
- Scroll until the evolve button is no longer parallel with the exit button.

Comment: It's a "UI Bug" in that it was introduced by the devs to stop accidental evolutions/new moves. Nobody wins, the way it's designed.

Comment: Great thanks and can I get rid of said U bug?

Comment: @neebug unfortunately when it comes to bugs, we just gotta wait until Niantic patches it

Comment: I have noticed that tapping the far left of the evolve button tends to get past the exit button.